# Trying to extract text from a list of webelements, but I only get the first one

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get the text from all web elements, for further processing using regex, but I only get the text from the first one. For the rest I get

**Error:**

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

I'm using the css selector, and in the devtools I can clearly see, this selector finds all `webelements` I want.

```
def get_package_value_list(self, SELECTOR):
    value_list = self.browser.find_elements(*SELECTOR)
    result_list=[]

    for value in value_list:
        print(value.text)
        value = re.sub(r'[\n]',',',value.text)
        regex = re.search(Utilities.URL_REGEX_PATTERN, value)
        result_list.append(regex.group())

    return result_list
```

Comment: error shows that it can't find your pattern in `value` so it returns `None`. Use `print(regex)` to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but changing the line

```
value = re.sub(r'[\n]',',',value.text)
```

to

```
value = re.sub(r'\n',',', value.get_attribute("innerText"))
```

helped, and now everything works as designed. But still confuses me, why it has to be this way, despite having this function working before with another invoke of it in another place in the code...